# Python - remove row index and insert column titles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
    a   b   
1   z   z
2   z   z
0   
0
1   z   z
2   z   z
```

I would like to remove the 0s from the row indexes, and populate the second of those with the column titles, such that the end result is:

```
    a   b   
1   z   z
2   z   z
    
    a   b
1   z   z
2   z   z
```

How do I achieve this?

If you're wondering why, it's because I'm writing this dataframe to an Excel sheet, and need distinct tables in order to filter and sort them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is before remove rows with `0` in index create groups column `g` used for loop in `groupby` and write each group to `excel` with one empty row:

```
m = df.index == 0
df = df.assign(g = m.cumsum())
df = df[~m]
print (df)
   a  b  g
1  z  z  0
2  z  z  0
1  z  z  2
2  z  z  2

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

start = 0
for k, g in df.groupby('g'):
    g.drop('g', axis=1).to_excel(writer, startrow=start)
    start += len(g) + 2
    
writer.save()
```

EDIT: t is possible, but not recommended, because mixed data - columns names with empty strings and data, so next processing complicated (mainly if some numeric data):

```
m = df.index == 0
df = df.assign(g = m.cumsum())
df = df[~m]

df = pd.concat([g.append(pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns), df.columns], 
                                      columns=df.columns, index=['',''])).drop('g', axis=1) 
                for k, g in df.groupby('g')]).iloc[:-2]

print (df)
   a  b
1  z  z
2  z  z
       
   a  b
1  z  z
2  z  z
```

Comment: Is there a solution which does not involve manipulation of only the final product in Excel? I've upvoted, but I'd like to have the final output in a dataframe.

Comment: @Thev - It is possible, but not recomennded, because mixed data - columns names with data rows, next processing not easy. Answer was edited